# Using webix with flask

Tags: python, flask, webix

I am trying to understand the webix framework and use it with my flask application. All the documentation deals with either static data in the html file or php examples.

A simple html file to populate a datatable looks like this (according to the
documentation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/webix.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../static/js/webix.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Webix Test 4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      webix.ui({
          id:"dtable",
          view:"datatable",
          url:"/gettabledata"
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my flask router I have done the following (from a tutorial) :-

```
peopleData = {'data':[
    {'title': "01. Basique", 'duration': "3:38"},
    {'title': "02. Moon", 'duration': "3:47"},
    {'title': "03. Unsaid", 'duration': "3:48"},
    {'title': "04. Eitheror", 'duration': "5:45"},
    {'title': "05. Above the Clouds", 'duration': "3:50"}]}
return jsonify(peopleData)
```

The web page shows nothing.

I have a similar problem trying to understand how to load variables (such as a page title) using python and flask.

Clearly I am missing something fundamental in how webix works with python/flask.
(Pages with embedded data work ok, no problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to try it without using Flask

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Webix Test 4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
webix.ui({
    rows: [{
        view: "template",
        type: "header",
        template: "My App!"
        }, {
            view: "datatable",
            autoConfig: true,
            editable: true,
            data: [
        {'title': "01. Basique", 'duration': "3:38"},
        {'title': "02. Moon", 'duration': "3:47"},
        {'title': "03. Unsaid", 'duration': "3:48"},
        {'title': "04. Eitheror", 'duration': "5:45"},
        {'title': "05. Above the Clouds", 'duration': "3:50"}]
        }]
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`python3 -m http.server 9004`

[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gdiamond/vwe9ap26/1/)

then try it with Flask

```
<script>
var my_data =  webix.ajax().get("http://localhost:9004/my_route");
webix.ui({
    rows: [{
        view: "template",
        type: "header",
        template: "My App!"
        }, {
            view: "datatable",
            autoConfig: true,
            editable: true,
            data: my_data
        }]
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get use of moving between flask , HTML & JS (using Jinja)
for example in your example, you can reflect data from dataframe in python

```
mynested_data  =  [{'title': "01. Basique", 'duration': "3:38"},
        {'title': "02. Moon", 'duration': "3:47"},
        {'title': "03. Unsaid", 'duration': "3:48"},
        {'title': "04. Eitheror", 'duration': "5:45"},
        {'title': "05. Above the Clouds", 'duration': "3:50"}]
```

then jsos.dumps it:

```
mynested_data = json.dumps(mynested_data)
```

finally, use it in render_template

```
render_template('index.html',mynested_data = mynested_data)
```

in html you can call it using the following:

```
{{mynested_data|safe}}
```